# Javascript RegEx Syntax Snafu

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string.  I want to allow for upper case letters, lower case letters, numbers, and these special characters: `!$/%@#`.

I would expect this to pass: `abcABC123!`

I would expect this to fail: `abcABC123*`

I have tried the following code:

```
var myString = 'abcABC123*'
// var myString = 'abcABC123!'

if (myString.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]!\$\/%@#/)) {
    alert('this works!');
} else {
    alert('Invalid Character');
}
```

As the code sits now, I always hit the else statement.  Be gentle I am not a RegEx expert, or an expert of any kind for that matter.

Note:  I would appreciate a pure JavaScript Solution.

Comment: Should the special character(s) be at the end?

Comment: I *think* you can, I just am missing something with the syntax...

Comment: Should `!abcABC123` match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes as should abc@123ABC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the snippet, change the regEx pattern to `^[a-zA-Z0-9!%@#]+$/g` so this could easily work

```js
var myString = 'abcABC123%'
// var myString = 'abcABC123!'

if (myString.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!\%\$@#]+$/g )) {
    alert('this works!');
} else {
    alert('Invalid Character in your password');
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is it you want to talk about? I think I have Skype installed

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am a javascript developer, I need to learn canvas and canvas image cropper. and a bit more javascript logic. I need a good tutor to guide me. Guide me means I want to support and some logic that i cannot do myself. I am not an  expert so..... `akhilaravindsb@live.in`If you feel free to guide me please add me on skype

Comment: I have basically no experience with Canvas nor image cropping, sorry, I would have to look up a tutorial and figure things out myself first

Comment: @CertainPerformance okay, thank you for the reply. It will be helpful if I get your skype id

Answer (score 2):

Add those characters to the character set and use `$` for asserting position at end of string:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9!$/%@#]+$
```

Check the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/NeqNNj/3).

Snippet:

```js
var myString = 'abcABC123!'
    
    if (myString.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9!$/%@#]+$/)) {
        console.log('this works!');
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid Character');
    }
```

Check a live JavaScript fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xag3huvo/46/).

Comment: I would also recommend using the regex `.test` method instead of the string `.match` method if all you want to do is see if the string adheres to that regex or not. EG: `/^[A-Za-z0-9!$\/%@#]+$/.test(myString)`. The `.match` is more appropriate when you need to use capture groups.

Comment: dang it I was way off, thanks for the fiddle and link.